# How to add default value to Django Sessions

Tags: python, django, session

I'm making a multi-language site, and would like to have a default language set to a specific one. How would I add a default value to every new session? Namely, I would like to `request.session['lang'] = 'de'` to be the default value upon creation of every new session.

By default, 'lang' is not stored in request.session, and attempting to call `request.session['lang']` for purpose of finding out the prefered language of a user, would return Key error unless 'lang' has been set beforehand. So instead of checking for and setting default language in every view, how would I go about making `<'lang':'de'>` part of every new session?

Comment: add it with a `middleware`

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference

Namely: 

request.LANGUAGE_CODE will give you the language of the user, with languages defined in settings as LANGUAGES.

Comment: How about `request.session.get('lang', 'de')`?